# I need to parse this JSON response make with http request in swift

Tags: json, swift, post, http-post

This is my script in php to have a Json response

```
<?php
include "dbconnect.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$uname = $_POST['uname'];

try {
 $queryExistingBike = "SELECT StatoBici, Username FROM BICI INNER JOIN UTENTE ON utenteKEY = KEYutente WHERE (IdBike = '$id')";
 $search = $connection->query($queryExistingBike);

    //print_r ($search);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$dati = $search->fetch_assoc();

if ($dati["Username"] == "$uname") {
  $dati['Username'] = "true";
} else {
  $dati['Username'] = "false";
}
//print_r($dati);
print json_encode($dati);
 ?>
```

This is the Json response from php script

```
{"StatoBici":"ok","Username":"false"}
```

This is the code in swift to make a http post request to web service

```
    func jsonResponse(){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://bike1010.com/webservice/getBikeData.php")!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "id=2017&uname=admin"  // Your parameter
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

            }

            let responseString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[])
            print(responseString)


        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

The output into Xcode

```
Optional({
    StatoBici : Ok
    Username : Tue
})
```

Comment: So what is the question? You have already parsed JSON and printed the result. What do you want to achieve? You want to parse it to an object, to get to use each of the results value for key?

Answer (score 2):

if that's what you wanted to achieve:

```
let responseString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String:Any]
print(responseString)
//simple example for receiving each field from response
let statoBici:String = responseString["StatoBici"] as! String
let username:Bool = responseString["Username"] as! Bool
print("StatoBici received: \(statoBici), username received: \(username)")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Wojcik mentioned in comment you already have parse JSON. Your `responseString` is actually parsed object. You can access values as:

```
if let obj = responseString as? NSDictionary {
   let StatoBici = obj.value(for : "StatoBici") as! String
   let okValue   = obj.value(for : "OK") as! String // If OK is bool use bool
}
```